# How to return exact matches for ManyToMany queries

Tags: python, django, orm

let's say I have a model like

```
class Group:
    users = ManyToMany(User, related_name='groups')
```

and I have groups with a different mixture of users

```
group1 = Group(users=[user1])
group2 = Group(users=[user1, user2])
group3 = Group(users=[user1, user2, user3])
```

How would I go about querying for groups only with `user1` and `user2`?

I'd like to do something that's like `Group.objects.filter(users=[user1, user2]) -> [group2]`

but I'm getting
`TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got [<User: user1>, <User: user2>]`.

if I do `Group.objects.filter(user__in=[user1, user2].distinct('id')`

it returns back all the groups `[group1, group2, group3]`

I know how to go through the `User` instance to get all of the user's groups but I specifically want to go through the `Group` model.

I imagine I may have to do some type of matching with the ORM... maybe a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

# since Django-2.0

users = [user1, user2, user3]
users = set(users)

group1 = Group.objects.annotate(
    nusers=Count('users'),
    nuser_match=Count('users', filter=Q(users__in=users))
).filter(
    nusers=len(users),
    nusers_match=len(users)
)
```

This will thus count the total number of related users, as well as the number of users that match. Both these numbers should equal the number of users in the set.

Comment: great answer, and I realized that taking out the `nusers` portion from the query makes it a query for finding groups that contain those users which is also very useful